# Magento 2 : How to pass json ecoded array in custom API

Tags: magento2, api, custom, magento2.3

I have created custom API that excepting 'mixed' type parameter and returning the 'string' as I defined. In interface I define parameter type 'mixed'. As I am trying to pass array as json_encode, it giving me `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in` error.` Please let me know how can I pass json array as parameter and return the same.

Here is my code -
etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="POST" url="/V1/managecustomers">
        <service class="Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface" method="createUpdate"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

etc/di.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Managecustomer"/>
</config>
```

Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface.php :-

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Api;

```
interface ManageCustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param mixed $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function createUpdate($data);
}
```

Namespace\Modulename\Model\Managecustomer.php - :

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

use Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface;

class Managecustomer implements ManageCustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param mixed $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function createUpdate($data) {
        $data = json_decode($data);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        return "Hello";

    }
}
```

If i am passing 'data' parameter as string like  - 
`$customerData = [
    'data' => "Abcd"
];`

Then its running fine. 
But If i am trying to pass 'data' as array like-

```
$customerData = [
    'data' => [
        "email" => "user@example.com",
        "firstname" => "John",
        "lastname" => "Doe",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1,
        "address"=>[
            "street" => "phase-1",
            "phone_no"=> "321654213"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Then its giving error - `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in` error.`

Here is my testapi.php file code  -

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/mage23/index.php/rest/all/V1/managecustomers");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

**Please let me know how can I pass array as parameter in API.**

Comment: try it as `(string)json_encode($customerData)`

Comment: thax #Aman, but its not working.

Comment: where is your data processing interface?

Comment: I didn't create it, is it necessary ?

Comment: I think so you must need a getter and setter for your data so that your json data get passed in process

Comment: actually I don't know how to create that and how that will work for this, Can you please share the specific code that I can use......

Comment: Ok will add it in answer

Comment: #Aman, please, it will be a great help...

Comment: Ok wait for some time

Comment: Okay.................

Comment: you hould never use the keyword `mixed`when working with APIs. it's bad practice

Comment: Check the given url for basic understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/75999131/15131271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added proper docblock and still getting this error, replace 
`@param mixed` to `@param string[]` or `@param mixed[]` as according to magento devdocs.

> Valid scalar types include: mixed (or anyType), bool (or boolean), str
>   (or string), integer (or int), float, and double.

Also note that you must always use fully qualified class name or a fully qualified interface name in docblock.

**Reference :**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to return paramters type of `Namespace\Modulename\Model\Managecustomer::createUpdate()` is wrong.

```
 /**
     * 
     *  @param array $data
     * @return string
     */

    public function createUpdate( array $data) {
    // donot need json_decode
        //$data = json_decode($data);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        return "Hello";

    }
```

Also, at `Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface`, DO NOT use PHP7 scalar argument types or return types as you want to hook this into the REST API!.

So:

```
   /**
     * 
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface[] $data
   * @return string
   */

public function createUpdate(array $data);
```

Comment: why I need this `@param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface[] $data`, And I applied json_decode just because i want to use that passed data here. 

and  Is  'array' "@param array $data" type allowed?

Comment: Because of  array  is PHP7 scalar argument  type and if  you will use this then you we will get error.

Comment: I am getting this error now -  [message] => Class array does not exist

Comment: Change `public function createUpdate(array $data);` to public function createUpdate($data); at `Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface`

Comment: did the same, but still giving same error -  [message] => Class array does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface.php :-

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Api;

interface ManageCustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param string $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function createUpdate($data);
}
```

Namespace\Modulename\Model\Managecustomer.php - :

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

```
use Namespace\Modulename\Api\ManageCustomerInterface;

class Managecustomer implements ManageCustomerInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param string $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function createUpdate($data) {
        $data = json_decode($data,TRUE);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); 
        die;
    }
}
```

in testapi.php file code use :-

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/mage23/index.php/rest/V1/managecustomers");
or
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/mage23/rest/V1/managecustomers");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working and tested version of your problem

For running API recieve POST data your must need below mentioned files and methods.

Here is the list of files needed.

Note: Replace Amanweb with your module vendor and Testapi with your module name.

Amanweb\Testapi\Api\TestapiRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Amanweb\Testapi\Api;

interface TestapiRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * create update customer
     * @api
     * @param mixed $param
     * @return array
     */
    public function createUpdate($param);
}
```

Amanweb\Testapi\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Amanweb\Testapi\Api\TestapiRepositoryInterface" type="Amanweb\Testapi\Model\TestapiRepository" />
</config>
```

Amanweb\Testapi\etc\webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/managecustomers" method="POST">
        <service class="Amanweb\Testapi\Api\TestapiRepositoryInterface" method="createUpdate"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Amanweb\Testapi\Model\TestapiRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace Amanweb\Testapi\Model;

use Amanweb\Testapi\Api\TestapiRepositoryInterface;

class TestapiRepository implements TestapiRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createUpdate($param)
    {
        return json_encode($param);
    }
}
```

testapi.php

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://magento.amanweb.in/rest/V1/managecustomers");
$customerData = [
    "param" => [
            "email" => "user@example.com",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1,
            "address"=>[
                "street" => "phase-1",
                "phone_no"=> "321654213"
            ]
        ]
];
echo json_encode($customerData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($result));
```

Here is your test live test url: http://magento.amanweb.in/test.php

Comment: Thx #Aman its working fine, but two things, 1 - its giving error on 'Swagger' (Failed to load API definition.
) and 2- In model function if I am trying to print passed parameter like 'echo "<pre>"; var_dump($param); die;' , its returning 'NULL'. 

Can you please check at your end also, how can I access passed parameter in Model function ?

Comment: where you getting this error on 'Swagger' (Failed to load API definition. ) . Regarding var dump i have tested print_r and its worked.

Comment: Here is mine model function with print statement -  `public function createUpdate($data) {
        //$data = json_decode($data,TRUE);
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); die;
        return json_encode($data);
    }`

And on 'Swagger' on landing page. 
Can you please share link to download your module ? FYI i am working on Mage2.3

Comment: just `var_dump($data)` instead of decoding json

Comment: Can you please share zip file of your module, via ur site url

Comment: http://www.amanweb.in/Testapi.zip

Comment: use Custom\Module\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

class test implements \Custom\Nodule\Api\TestInterface
{
    public function getOrdersOueue(OrderInterface $order)
    { 

    }
how to fetch the value